# Who is the Titans' benefactor

Tags: dc, comics, character-identification, episode-identification

So. I'm a new fan of DC Comics and I've read Titans #7 and it said the Titans has a benefactor. I've read some review blog that said the benefactor is Batman, but I just want to make sure of it and what issues I can read where this benefactor involved?

Comment: Are we talking Teen Titans or the subsequent [Titans](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Titans)?

Comment: The subsequent Titans, the one with Dick, Wally, Garth, and the others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Teen Titans were backed by [Loren Jupiter](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/loren-jupiter/4005-46936/) (emphasis mine)

> Various years after the disbanding of the original team of Teen Titans, Loren Jupiter along with his assistant Omen (Lilith Clay) **would appear once more in order to fund a new generation of Teen Titans** that was formed by Prysm, Fringe, Joto (Hotspot), Risk, Argent and was leaded by a de-aged version of Ray Palmer (The Atom).

[Also](http://www.titanstower.com/loren-jupiter/) (emphasis mine)

> After the accidental death of pacifist Arthur Swenson – a death the Teen Titans were unable to prevent – Loren invited the Titans to abandon their superhero guises and join his project. After Robin solved the Swenson case, the Titans were free to don their costumes once more, and **Jupiter continued to finance them.**

Here's Jupiter bossing Ray Palmer around

[image]

Comment: Why is Ray flinching away? Does Jupiter have telekinesis or something?

Comment: So, batman really is not involved in their finance? and in what age is this happening?

Comment: I don't know about which age this happens, but Jupiter seems to be the consistent backer of the Teen Titans, and probably the subsequent Titans as well. I don't know that Bruce Wayne ever finances them, probably because, in at least one point, [he helped finance the Justice League](https://www.reddit.com/r/DCcomics/comments/1h5sn9/so_where_does_the_justice_league_get_funding/).